# Mysql - using numbers in Match Against

Tags: mysql, match-against

I want to convert this mysql code using the match against clause

```
Select * from table_1 Where age >= 2 && age <= 10
```

What would be the equivalent for this in match against?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MYSQL table engine must be MyISAM and doesn't support  less than < or > greater than for "**MATCH AGAINST**" see this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html) for more info.

```
search_modifier:
  {
       IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE
     | IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE WITH QUERY EXPANSION
     | IN BOOLEAN MODE
     | WITH QUERY EXPANSION
  }
```